# Conversion between Local to UTC and UTC to Local using JodaTime

Tags: jodatime

I am developing a chat application where users might be using the app from different countries. In order to show the correct date and time, I am using JodaTime api and converting Local time to UTC before saving it in database. That conversion seems fine. But, UTC to local time is not showing the correct results. Please see my code below and recommend me the best solution.

```
public static Date convertLocalToUTC(Date date)
{
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "local date:"+date);
        DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
        Date targetDate = new Date(tz.convertLocalToUTC(date.getTime(), false));
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "utc date:"+targetDate);
        return targetDate;
}


public static Date convertUTCToLocal(Date date)
{
        DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "utc date:"+date);
        Date targetDate = new Date(tz.convertUTCToLocal(date.getTime()));
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "local date:"+targetDate);
        return targetDate;
}
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using the new time libraries in Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using java.util.Date completely. Note that java.util.Date represents an **instant**, it is free of timezone information. Transforming it "from UTC to local" is not a valid concept.

Sad to say, the JDBC interface still requires use of java.sql.Timestamp/java.sql.Date etc and this can require driver-specific fixing to get the right thing stored. Not all JDBC implementors understand how date/time works in Java either. Passing ISO-formatted strings to the database might be clearer.

For example, this is the code we use with MySQL to transform JodaTime Instants to java.sql.Timestamp:

```
    st.setTimestamp(index,
                    new java.sql.Timestamp(instant.toDateTime(DATABASE_TIMEZONE)
                                                  .withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
                                                  .getMillis()));
```

This is necessary because the MySQL driver insists on reading the java.sql.Timestamp as the default timezone. Similar shenanigans are necessary to read the timestamp back out:

```
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(names[0]);
    return new DateTime(timestamp.getTime())
                .withZoneRetainFields(DATABASE_TIMEZONE)
                .toInstant();
```